# Intellij IDEA dont find properties files

Tags: intellij-idea, properties-file

I prefer using IntelliJ IDEA but my company uses NetBeans, in it project works just fine, but when I start to fire it up on IDEA I am getting that it can't find **.properties  files

Structure is something like that:

```
project-src/all modules here
confs/properties-dir/**.properties
```

Error I am getting:

```
`Failed to open [file:PATH_TO_PROJECT/Ext.appHomeDir_IS_UNDEFINED/logback.xml] `
```

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: PATH_TO_PROJECT/Ext.appHomeDir_IS_UNDEFINED\logback.xml`
`(The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileNotFoundException: PATH_TO_PROJECT/Ext.appHomeDir_IS_UNDEFINED\logback.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)`

Comment: What project type do you use?  I don't think IDEA can read native (ant style) Netbeans projects properly, but from first-hand experience I can assure you Maven projects can shuttle between Netbeans and IDEA developers smoothly.

Comment: It looks like your PATH_TO_PROJECT placeholder variable is not correclty filled in. Try to find out how it can be set. Maybe try with specifying as an en environment parameter in IntelliJ